# ¿Como poner nombres a los ejes de una grafica en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Re-hice un código para calcular inversiones (no es muy bueno pero funciona bien) pero estoy teniendo problemas para poder ponerle nombre a los ejes para el tiempo y el dinero que puede ganar ¿Que tengo que hacer para ponerles nombres a los ejes?
a estoy usando el módulo de matplotlib

```
#Esta es la parte de la grafica 

x = np.zeros(n)

y = np.zeros(n)

tiempo = 0

for i in range(0, n):    #la n es la variable que introducirá el usuario



    tiempo = tiempo+1 #el tiempo avanzara de uno en uno en años

    x[i] = tiempo

    y[i] = interes(cantidad, tasa, tiempo, periodo)



plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'green')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar los métodos [`xlabel()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html) y [`ylabel()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel.html) de `plt`.

```py
plt.xlabel('Eje de las x')
plt.ylabel('Eje de las y')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo probe y funciono muy bien.

Comment: @Gargantia genial!, si la respuesta te valió deberías aceptarla :-)